# How to delay calls to api inside a foreach loop with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to place a delay between api calls within a `for loop`. 
I've tried using the `setTimeout()` without any luck.

**Here is the code:**

```
for(let pc = 0; pc < this.cModel.stuff.length; pc++)
{   
   for(let mc = 0; mc < this.cModel.stuff[pc].otherStuff.length; mc){
       let mp = this.mcModel.stuff[pc].otherStuff[mc];

       //method that calls api ***need delay***
       this.callCancel(mp.key, cp.key);
   }
}
private (mpkey: string, cpkey: string){
       //code that builds up object *obj
       //for api call here

       this.executeApiCallHere(obj);
    }
```

**Here is what I've tried:**

- I've tried putting the setTimeout() inside the forloop as such:

  ```
  setTimeout(this.callCancel(mp.key, cp.key), 1000);
  ```
- I've tried putting the setTimeout() inside the method that calls the api as such:

  ```
  setTimeout(() => { this.executeApiCallHere(obj);}, 1000);
  ```
- I've tried placing the setTimeout() around the forloop as such:

  ```
  setTimeout(function () { ......code ....}, 1000);
  ```

All of the above result with no delay between calls.
How should I handle this in Typescript so that `foreach` item in the `forloop` there is a delay between calls?

Comment: you should use rxjs for this. I can post an example if you're interested in trying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run a loop 10 times and call `setTimeout` in that loop with 1 second the result will be a 1 second delay and then a rapid continues fire of the callbacks that you had delayed. The result is an *initial* delay but not a delay *between* calls.

If you want to delay *between* calls you have to increase the timeout between each call of `setTimeout`. You can do this with a counter or using the value in the `for` loop (depending on the places you call it).

Example

```
var timeoutSeconds = 1;

for(let pc = 0; pc < this.cModel.stuff.length; pc++)
{   
   for(let mc = 0; mc < this.cModel.stuff[pc].otherStuff.length; mc){

      setTimeout(() => this.callCancel(mp.key, cp.key), 1000 * timeoutSeconds);
      timeoutSeconds++;

   }
}
```

Comment: In this case `pc` and `mc` are already counters so you don't need `timeoutSeconds` :) Also, the keyword `this` loses its scope, you can prevent that with `setTimeout(() => this.callCancel(mp.key, cp.key), 1000 * mc);`

Comment: @Kokodoko - good catch on this losing scope! On the counters this is just an example to illustrate the point that calling it repeatedly with 1 second as the 2nd argument will not space anything. I did not use `mc` because the value will reset back to 0 each time the outer loop iterates and I did not want to assume that the next (set) of calls should or should not also be spaced from the first set. The OP can edit it as he sees fit.

Answer (score 2):

[`async` / `await`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/async-await.html) are your friends:

```
async function modelStuff() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {
            await apiCall(i);
        } catch (err) {
            // do we keep going?
            // do we drop the rest?
            // do we maybe need to relogin and retry last request?
        }
        await sleep(500);
    }
}

async function apiCall(ix) {
    console.log(`call: ${ix}`);
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// test it
modelStuff();
```